# JQuery - Compare only a part of the text of all the options inside a select input, and select the one that matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next select input:

```
<h6>Opciones: </h6> 
<select id="id_opciones" name="elegir_opciones">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">1-Primero-0 </option>
<option value="2">2-Segundo-2000.00</option>
<option value="3">3-Caja-0 </option>
<option value="4">4-Tercero-4000.00</option>
<option value="5">5-Cuarto-6000.00</option>
</select>
```

And also a variable that I get form a table, lets think that this is the variable:

```
var comparar=5000;
```

What I want to do is to compare the last value of the text inside the option, with the variable `comparar`, lets take the last item as an example:

```
<option value="5">5-Cuarto-6000.00</option>
```

The value that I want to compare to `comparar` is `6000.00` (I know how to get this value, with split), and do that with options 2, 4 and 5.

The conditions will be something like this:

```
if (option2_value<=comparar && comparar<option4_value){
  //select option 2
}

if (option4_value<=comparar && comparar<option5_value){
  //select option 4
}

if (comparar>=option5_value>){
  //select option 5
}
```

Probably the main question is, how to make a personalized selector for a select input?

Comment: `+'2-Segundo-2000.00'.split('-')[2];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var option1_value = ($('#id_opciones option:eq(1)').text()).split('-')[2];
      var option2_value = ($('#id_opciones option:eq(2)').text()).split('-')[2];
      var option3_value = ($('#id_opciones option:eq(3)').text()).split('-')[2];
      var option4_value = ($('#id_opciones option:eq(4)').text()).split('-')[2];
      var option5_value = ($('#id_opciones option:eq(5)').text()).split('-')[2];
      if(option2_value <= comparar && comparar < option4_value){
        $('#id_opciones option:eq(2)').attr("selected",true)
      }
      else if (option4_value <= comparar && comparar < option5_value){
        $('#id_opciones option:eq(4)').attr("selected",true)
      }
      else if (comparar >= option5_value ){
        $('#id_opciones option:eq(5)').attr("selected",true)
      }

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Actualy yes, that code only gets the specific part of the text that I want, but that don't solves the problem, what I want to do is to select the option that meets the condition. I have used this for only text: `$("#select_id option:contains("+variable+")").attr('selected', true);` with that the selected option changes to the one that contains the text inside `variable`, I want to do something like that, but It my special conditions.

Comment: i have updated my answer.I assume this is what u want if not please let me know @elG

Comment: It works :D thank you so much, I was thinking in something more complicated, like overriding the selector, because I have found a code that does that, instead of using "contains" it uses "starts-with" but i didn't understand a single line of code of that override haha. Thank you again :D

Comment: Glad! It helped!! you can accept the answer so others can find it easier @elG

Answer (score 0):

The optimized way for getting the text value of a selected option: 
`$( "#id_opciones option:selected" ).text();` 
Refer this [link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)